# Need to convert chararray to datetime in specific format in PIG

Tags: apache-pig, etl, orc

In my pig code a variable event_date is calculated like this:

```
SUBSTRING(case when join_start_ts is NULL or TRIM(join_start_ts)=='' then 'null' else join_start_ts end,0,10) as event_date;
```

Where event_date looks like this (for Eg):  2018-04-30 00:00:00.0  (NOTE: All of hours, sec, mins should be zero)

In DDL table (where event_date variable is stored after calculation is done), the event_date variable is defined as:

```
........
,event_date timestamp
)
PARTITIONED BY (data_input_date string) 
stored as orc
location 
'${hiveconf:s3bucket}/${hiveconf:fact_path}/${hiveconf:join_failure_fact}/'
TBLPROPERTIES ("orc.compress"="snappy");
```

While doing calculation (as shown above) I only want to change event_date format to datetime in such a way that all of its hours,mins,sec part are Zero.

For this, I have tried 2 things:

- **By using todate()** function outside of SUBSTRING but that is not supported in Pig. If no SUBSTRING would have been present then I could have used ToDate function though.
- I used this below calculation method and using it, event_date is coming in the datetime format but it looks like this (For eg) :  2018-04-30 17:03:50.798 (I want all of hours,sec,mins to be Zero)

  `(case when join_start_ts is NULL or TRIM(join_start_ts)=='' then NULL else ToDate(join_start_ts) end) as eventdate;`

What should I do so that in the variable calculation of event_date, it looks like 2018-04-30 00:00:00.0 and should be in datetime format ?

Answer (score 0):

If join_start_ts is already in required datetime format but as a string then you could use `substring` to get the date part and then  `concat` '00:00:00.0'. If it is in milliseconds or in a different format then use `todate, tostring, substring, and concat`.Finally cast it back to datetime.

```
(case 
     when join_start_ts is NULL or TRIM(join_start_ts) == '' then NULL
     else Concat(SubString(join_start_ts,0,11),'00:00:00.0') 
end) as eventdate;
```

OR

```
(case 
     when join_start_ts is NULL or TRIM(join_start_ts) == '' then NULL
     else Concat(SubString(ToString(ToDate(join_start_ts)),0,11),'00:00:00.0') 
end) as eventdate;
```

Comment: By using above 2 methods you have told, the output will be in chararray format and not in datetime format.  And if I try to use ToDate() outside this then it will throw error

Comment: Finally cast it back to datetime.Read the full answer